# Java2d thumbnails. Can I get thumbnail from OS

Tags: java, image, swing

I develop an application in which I want to display a grid with a list of images. For each image I create an instance of a class myImage. MyImage class, extends JCompoment and create an thumbnail and after draw it with overide thepaintCompoment(Graphics g).

All is ok, but in big size images I have a lot of delay to create the thumbnail.

Now I think to when I scan the folders for image(to create the list I said above to create an thumbanail of each image and save it to disc. For each image I will have a database record to save the image path and thumbnail path.So is this a good solution of the problem? 
 Is there a way to get the thumbnails of the system creates for each image, in file manager. Or a more effective solution than I try.

Thank you!!

Comment: which system are you talking about ? in Gnome, it seems to be stored in `~/.thumbnails/normal/`md5sum $file`.png` (although the `md5sum` is just a simple guess :)

Comment: Thank you Kevin for you answer! yes now I develop in gnome, but I want to deploy the application and for windows. Yes I found a lot of thumbnails in that directory.If you know that directories contains thumbnails for all the media files that I have in my pc, or I should at least once, open the image file with nautilus, for the thumbnail to being created. Also Is there a some folder in windows (xp, vista,7) so depending the os Linux system with gnome or windows to create 2 seperate instance of my application or get the thumbnail from the appropriate folder. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use something like imagemagick to convert the image and create the thumbnail. There's a project called [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org/) which provides JNI hooks into Imagemagick, but running a process work too.

Imagemagick is heavily optimized C code for manipulating images. It will also be able to handle images that Java won't and with much less memory usage.

I work for a website where we let users upload art and create thumbnails on the fly, and it absolutely needs to be fast, so that's what we use.

The following is Groovy code, but it can modified to Java code pretty easily:

```
public boolean createThumbnail(InputStream input, OutputStream output){        

    def cmd = "convert -colorspace RGB -auto-orient -thumbnail 125x125 -[0] jpg:-"

    Process p = cmd.execute()
    p.consumeProcessErrorStream(System.out)
    p.consumeProcessOutputStream(output)
    p.out << input
    p.out.close()

    p.waitForOrKill(8000)
    return p.exitValue()==0
}
```

This creates a thumbnail using pipes without actually writing any data to disk. The outputStream can be to a file if you wanted to immediately write it as well.

Comment: Note: If you plan to release to Windows, you'll need to use JMagick instead of the console application. It should be faster as well.

Comment: +1 Interesting idea; can you comment on the dependancy burden?

Comment: Thank you,yes I will try to use JMagic, and check If I will have less delay in the thumbnail creation, than my Java code.

Comment: Well, for server apps, using the command line tool works fine since you have full control over the environment. ForWindows it's still possible, but it's sloppy as hell, so Jmagick is better.

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid OS dependance is to use [`getScaledInstance()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29), as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170777). See the [cited articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170777) for certain limitations. If it's taking too long, use a [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to do the load and scale in the background.

Comment: Thank you. I change my code to create the thumb, with use the getScaledInstance() but after some photos loaded I get a memory error. I will study about the SwingWorker.       In the below answer what are you mean with the "+1 Interesting idea; can you comment on the dependancy burden? "

Comment: A memory error suggests you may be unintentionally retaining objects. The dependancy burden is the effort needed to maintain and deploy a third party application of each targeted OS.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it for the creation of thumbnails, but you may also want to take a look at the ImageIO API.

[ImageIO](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html)

Comment: Thank you, that's already I use to create the thumbnails. And I will try the Milan Ramaiya's suggestion jMagick, to try to reduce the thumbnails's creation time.